# Sql Server database logs "missing"

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

Here's the problem we're having:

In the **applications** that are **using the databases** we get errors like:

```
The log for database 'redactedDatabaseName' is not available. Check the event log for related error messages. Resolve any errors and restart the database.
Cannot close event log because there are still event handle users active.
```

The **server log** says this:

```
Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 1.
```

**Context**:

The server in question is holding databases for a multi-tenant application and lately it's been under quite heavy loads.

It has something like 3k small databases on it and these errors have been coming in the last week.

We have a work-around right now, which is taking the database offline then bringing it online again.

Any ideas why this is happening and how we can fix it?

**Edit:**
Server specs: 2 Intel Xeon CPU 2.27GHz processors, 24 GB RAM, 4 x 500 GB HDDs in RAID 10 (SAS)

Comment: What does the server's event log have at around the same time?

Comment: Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 1.

Comment: Can you post the server's hardware specs?

Comment: Posted the server specs

Comment: What do the secs/read and secs/write numbers look like from performance monitor? Do they spike when you have problems? I would think that 2x500/RAID1 (are they SATA or SAS?) could get overwhelmed pretty quickly, unless you have a super-small amount of updates,

Comment: Turns out there are 4 SAS HDDs in a RAID 10 configuration.

Comment: Right now it's not acting up so I don't have numbers for secs/read and secs/write.

Comment: I don't believe there is only a single event log entry around that time. Put a custom query across all logs from 10 min before to 10 min after the time of the failure. Also need to know the log and source for events (not just some ids).

Answer (score 1):

Log corruption or hardware failure?

[SQL-Server-Performance.com forums: Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 4](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/error-9001-severity-21-state-4.5878/)

Also, from SQLServerPedia:

[Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 1 | The log for database ‘tempdb’ is not available](http://web.archive.org/web/20120111094744/http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/error-9001-severity-21-state-1-the-log-for-database-%E2%80%98tempdb%E2%80%99-is-not-available/)

Finally, check the mini-dump file in the SQL Server log folder.

Comment: I checked the system logs, there are no hardware errors for the disk.